# MySQL Access Denied For User on Other Laptop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a database using MySQL version 8.0.22 (I realize it's not the newest version but the newer version didn't work on my laptop). I need to have somebody (for who I made the database for) have full access to the database from their own laptop. I created their user with a password, granted full access, and flushed privileges.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1234!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON fsk TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However, I still got the error:

"Access denied for user 'user@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I have been googling this error for the past two days and have everything from making sure there aren't any duplicates that contain "%" instead of "localhost" to reinstalling the program. For even more clarification, when trying to connect on MySQL Workbench, I entered 'localhost' for the "Hostname" field (didn't use quotes around localhost), the correct username, and finally, the correct password (made sure after attempting plenty of times very slowly).

Am I missing something with trying to get this working? I really just need one user to have full access to the database from another laptop and I keep getting "Access Denied" when trying to log in as that user I have created.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Are they connecting remotely in some way? ... If so, then their host would not be localhost, but the IP from which they connect to the DB. (such as `'user'@'10.10.10.5'`)

Comment: can you use your ip address instead of 'localhost'?

Comment: Thank you Paul and Kaumadie for your feedback. I tried using the IP address instead of localhost (and even made the change in "Users and Privileges". However, after trying to log-in again, a pop-up appears that says "Failed to connect to MySQL at IP (what my IP address is):3306 with user. Unable to connect to the local host." While doing this, I also changed my root hostname to the IP address instead of localhost and locked me out of the database unfortunately so I'm in the process of fixing that. But do you know why it still said unable to connect to localhost when I used my IP address?

Comment: Is the default port in use, or some other port number? Also, ensure firewall not blocking. Other than that, I'd need more of the picture. If you login to the DB that is on the same PC, then that would be localhost. Any others that remotely connect to that PC would need their IP.

Comment: I think the problem may be that I need to change the bind_address from the configuration file to my IP address. However, I can't seem to find where the my.cnf is located using mac Big Slur. I'm going to open a separate question about this, but thanks for the help!